# How to get the picture of the custom badges?

Tags: support, design, badges

I am currently trying to get the picture of the badges used for ELL, any suggestions to how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the developer tools of your browser (in some browsers, you might need to enable them first). If you then right-click on the badge and choose 'Inspect' or a similarly worded option, you'll open a pane where the CSS is shown, including the URL to the image:

[image]

The URL is https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ellmeta/img/sprites.svg?v=8f2f88aa23c7 and it shows *all* custom design elements for ELL.SE (this is done for performance reasons), so you have to edit the file in an image editor.

Another, perhaps simpler, option would be to simply take a screenshot ...